# Source of a quote and a story

Tags: quote, mathematics-social-history

I read a story and a quote few years ago on a mathematical community in my country and today I just suddenly reminiscend of and want to know whether they are real or not and if it is the former case then I would like to have sources. Unfortunately, all the old posts in that forum were lost and even if they weren't, owners of those posts are no longer active.  I tried to find them on google but no result found at all.

- The story: as far as I can remember, it is about Faltings (Fields medalist) who once was playing chess with an Abel laureate but could not win a game. The Abel laureate then stood up and belike "I think we could stop, you cannot win even if we keep playing" but Falting stopped him and retorted "even knowing that you cannot get a Fields medal, why do you keep doing math?"
- And about the quote, it is attributed to Hirzebruch if I remember correctly. He said that the growth of technology would bring people back to mathematics, literature and poetry.

Comment: Please check the spellings: Abel laureteau? Also, write full names of the mathematicians for the sake of completeness and historical correctness.

Comment: Gerd Faltings.  Friedrich Hirzebruch.

Comment: Try Quote Investigator  https://quoteinvestigator.com/

Comment: @AChem Asking someone to correct their spellings or grammar when the meaning is clear, can be ableist and condescending. I am sure you didn't mean it that way but I would beg you to consider that perfect spellings may be difficult for some due to a variety of reasons (phone, keyboard, language, education, teacher, health, neurotype etc.).

Comment: @RiteshSingh, I am also not a native English speaker, in case you thought it that way. The first thing that came to mind was that Abel laureteau was a person's full name. Spelling mistakes can lead to misunderstandings for all the reasons you mentioned. This is why I respectfully requested that full names should be written in the original query. There was no ableist connotation.

Comment: @AChem Thank you for your clarification. I stand corrected.